# Regular expressions remove characters from string (regex)

Tags: regex

I have the following file name:

Document_1234567_JohnSmith_20140714-135020.docx

I would like to return only the first number portion from the string using a regular expression so the result is:

1234567

Also, is there a way of just stripping out "Document_" so I am left with:

1234567_JohnSmith_20140714-135020.docx

Comment: Can you detail your question a bit more - is the 'Document_' going to be prefixed on all your doc names? Will all your doc names follow this same general format? Or are you only looking for an answer for this specific doc name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match all the characters which are just after to the first `_`(underscore) symbol.

```
(?<=_).*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/25)

The below regex would match the first number. `Don't` forget to disable `g`(*global*) modifier.

```
\d+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eN2hY4/26)

Answer (score 0):

search pattern: `^[^_]+_(\d+)_.*`
replace with: `$1` (first matched group)

To strip off the "Document_" prefix,
search pattern `Document_(.*)`
replace with: `$1`